# Passing value in database.php in codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, parameter-passing

every client has its own database schema how should i pass a value to database.php so that the client can access its own database?

how i did it. if the client access his/her account the contoller need to    `$this->load->database('default', FALSE);` `$this->load->database($company_db, TRUE);`

```
$company_db['hostname'] = "localhost";
$company_db['username'] = "root";
$company_db['password'] = "";
$company_db['database'] = $replaced;
$company_db['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$company_db['dbprefix'] = "";
$company_db['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$company_db['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$company_db['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$company_db['cachedir'] = "";
$company_db['char_set'] = "utf8";
$company_db['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$this->load->database('default', FALSE); 
$this->load->database($company_db, TRUE);
```

what is the best way so that i will not keep on doing this. How should i make the `$company_db['database'] = $replaced;` static

Comment: every time a user register there will be a new schema created. i just want to change the value of the $user_db['database'] to the user who will log in. so everytime there is a user that will log.in the database name will change to the database assigned to that user

Answer (score 0):

Store in `application/config/database.php` all the databases with a leading index of the key to use.

EX

```
$db['db1']['host'] = "localhost";
$db['db1']['etc']

$db['db2']['host'] = "localhost";

$db['db3']['host'] = "localhost";
```

> The $active_group variable lets you choose which connection group
>   to   make active.  By default there is only one group (the 'default'
>   group).

So set `$active_group` to whatever. ex `db1` in this example.

Comment: every time a user register there will be a new schema created. i just want to change the value of the $user_db['database'] to the user who will log in. so everytime there is a user that will log.in the database name will change